# C#, sxstrace and the visual studio

Tags: c#, side-by-side, sxs

I have a question. Sometimes, there are occurring some side-by-side errors. One help to get the solution for this type of errors, there is a nice tool, called sxstrace.exe.

So when I start my program (TestProgram.exe), which has some errors in the manifest file, so an error is popping up, then I can use sxstrace to get the information, why this error occurs.

But I have one problem. When I start a process with sxstrace.exe in C#, and start my program (TestProgram.exe) with the manifest failure, sxstrace.exe will do not trace any error. Starting sxstrace.exe from shell, it will trace all errors.

Here is the question: Why is that? How can I start sxstrace.exe from C# so it will trace all errors?

EDIT: As far as the C#-program (which is starting a sxstrace process) is starting with admin rights, I suppose, that the sxstrace process also starts with admin rights.

Comment: I'm curious why you think you need a third party tool to get StackTrace.. when .Net Framework allows you to expose that..[C# MSDN StackTrace Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Look in the Windows Application event log first, sxstrace.exe doesn't have a lot of compelling features beyond that.

Comment: What cmd line do you use to start sxsrace?

Comment: @MethodMan, sxstrace has nothing to do with stack trace, it is for monitoring native assembly loading.

Answer (score -1):

OK, here is the answer to my question: In my C#-Code, I called my TestProgram.exe (which has the Side-by-Side-Error) with the Property `UseShellExecute = false`. I had to change it to `true`.